# finding the smallest Positive Missing intger in an array several times

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, greedy

I have this algorithm. How can I do it faster than `O(n^2)` ?

Here is the algorithm :

We are given an array of size `k` in one operation we choose the smallest positive missing integer from the last `k` elements of the array and we add it to the end of the array.

for example if `k = 4` and the array is `4 7 2 2`

after one operation the array becomes `4 7 2 2 1`

and after 2 operations it becomes `4 7 2 2 1 3` (the smallest positive missing integer between `7 2 2 1` is `3`)

after `k + 1` operations whats the final array ?

Comment: Sort  + merge with the integer sequence 1,2.. The resulting array is 2k + 1 in size. O(NlogN), done.

Comment: can you please explain more ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain more than provide the steps.
The code is straightforward.

first is the array, last is the array + size

```
auto first = array;
auto last = first + k;
std::sort(first, last);

unsigned seq = 1;
// merge
auto std::vector dest(k + k + 1);
auto d_i = dest.begin();
auto d_end = dest.end();
while (d_i != d_end){ // we should fill destination
    if(*first <= seq){
        *d_i++ = *first;
        if(seq == *first) seq++;
    }else{
        *d_i++ = seq++;
    }
}
```